# How to organize my Java code into classes

Tags: java, class

I will show you my code without any classes.

I need it divided in 3 classes which are Main class , First class , Second class.

for example ,
the main class
products class
and coding class maybe

```java
package vending.machine.project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class VendingMachineProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n=1;
        int x=1;
        int exit=0;
        double price = 0;
        double tax = 0.15;
        char choice;
        double finPrice=0;
        
        while(exit!=-1)
        {
            while(n!=5)
            {
                if(n>0&&n<5)
                {
                    System.out.print("1.Hot Drinks\n2.Soft Drinks\n"
                            + "3.Chips\n4.Sweets\n5.Exit\n\n");
                    System.out.print("Choose one of the types above: ");
                    n = keyboard.nextInt();
                    switch(n)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.print("1.Hot Chocolate (5$)\t\t\t2.Tea (2$)\n3.Caramel Latté (7$)\t\t\t"
                                    + "4.Turkish Coffee (6$)\n5.Espresso (8$)\t\t\t\t6.Green Tea (3$)\n\n");
                            System.out.print("What do you prefer to order Sir? write the number: ");
                            do
                            {
                                x = keyboard.nextInt();
                                if (x>0&&x<7)
                                {
                                    switch(x)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            price = price + 5;
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            price = price + 7;
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            price = price + 6;
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            price = price + 8;
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else 
                                    System.out.print("Please choose one of"
                                            + " the hot drinks above Sir: ");
                            }while(!(x>0&&x<7));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.print("1.Cocacola (2$)\t\t\t2.PEPSI (3$)\n3.Seven UP (1$)\t\t\t"
                                    + "4.Code Red (4$)\n5.Sprite (1$)\t\t\t6.Mirinda (2$)\n\n");
                            System.out.print("What do you prefer to order Sir? write the number: ");
                            do
                            {
                                x = keyboard.nextInt();
                                if (x>0&&x<7)
                                {
                                    switch(x)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            price = price + 4;
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else 
                                    System.out.print("Please choose one of"
                                            + " the soft drinks above Sir: ");
                            }while(!(x>0&&x<7));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.print("1.Lays (1$)\t\t\t2.Chips Oman (3$)\n3.Cheetos (3$)\t\t\t"
                                    + "4.Doritos (2$)\n5.Bugles (2$)\t\t\t6.AL Batal (1$)\n\n");
                            System.out.print("What do you prefer to order Sir? write the number: ");
                            do
                            {
                                x = keyboard.nextInt();
                                if (x>0&&x<7)
                                {
                                    switch(x)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else 
                                    System.out.print("Please choose one of"
                                            + " the Chips above Sir: ");
                            }while(!(x>0&&x<7));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.print("1.Oreo (1$)\t\t\t2.Kinder (4$)\n3.Bounty (3$)\t\t\t"
                                    + "4.Twix (3$)\n5.Galaxy (2$)\t\t\t6.Biscream (1$)\n\n");
                            System.out.print("What do you prefer to order Sir? write the number: ");
                            do
                            {
                                x = keyboard.nextInt();
                                if (x>0&&x<7)
                                {
                                    switch(x)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            price = price + 4;
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            price = price + 3;
                                            break;
                                        case 5:
                                            price = price + 2;
                                            break;
                                        case 6:
                                            price = price + 1;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else 
                                    System.out.print("Please choose one of"
                                            + " the sweets above Sir: ");
                            }while(!(x>0&&x<7));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            exit = -1;
                            break;
                    }
                    System.out.print("Do you want to order anything more Sir?"
                            + "type (y). If not Type (n) to Exit: ");

                    do{    
                        choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                        Character.toLowerCase(choice);
                        if(choice=='n'){
                            n = 5;
                            exit = -1;
                        }
                        else if(choice!='y'){
                            System.out.print("Please Sir choose (y) or (n): ");
                        }
                    }while(choice!='y'&&choice!='n'&&n!=5);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Please choose from the list Above: ");
                    n = keyboard.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what issue you are encountering. It sounds like you can't decide how to reorganize your code into classes. This is fundamentally opinion based and you should come to conclusions on your own at this point.

Comment: If you really want to learn Java, I believe that the best thing to do is to write some code and post your doubts or errors here, so that someone can help.

Comment: I was trying to finish this project yesterday , also I was working on it for 4 days. However, tomorrow is the last time that I can finish this project or I will lose 10 marks. this project was my idea and I didn't expect the doctor want me to do it in classes bcz we didn't study it very well.

Comment: @BassamAl-Suwaidan Classes are the main point of Java, being an [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language. I suspect you have missed some classes and/or textbook chapters.

Comment: You're asking us to split up your personal project into classes.  This site is supposed to be for questions, and those questions need to be worded such that they can help future users.  We are always happy to answer questions, but to be frank, this post is not a question.  Please be sure to read [ask] for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to study the basics of [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

There is no one exact best way to organize your code into classes. Even separating the better ways from the less optimal ways takes more information about the business that you have given here. But let's walk though the basics to get you going.

Look for the things, the [*entities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), from the real world that you are modeling in your app. Then list the attributes, the *properties*, that describe each particular entity.

I see products (food items) as an entity. Each product has a name, a price, and a category (hot drink, cold drink, chips, candy, and so on, as its attributes.

So write a class called `Product` to represent each product you are selling. In Java 16 and later, you might use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to more briefly write the class. A record is appropriate only for a class whose main purpose is to merely communicate data transparently and immutably, with a focus on state rather than behavior, and no inheritance.

```
public record Product ( String name , int price , String category ) {}
```

If you were further advanced, I'd suggest an enum for the category. But for now use a `String` with text.

Instantiate your products.

```
Product oreo = new Product( "Oreo" , 1 , "Cookie" ) ;
```

Another entity is the vending machine. The vending machine holds a list of products. Make another class for this.

```java
public class VendingMachine 
{
    // Member fields.
    final private List< Product > products ;
    …

    // Constructor.
    public VendingMachine() 
    {
        this.products = 
            List.of(
                new Product( "Oreo" , 1 , "Cookie" ) ,
                new Product( "Turkish Coffee" , 6 , "Hot drink" ) ,
                …
            )
        ;
        …
    }

    // Methods.
    …
    public List< Product > getProductsForCategory( String category )
    {
        … Loop all the products to find the ones whose assigned category matches this desired category.
    }
}
```

That vending machine object knows how to search its list of products to produce a subset of products by category. So we have the `getProductsForCategory` method. That method returns an ordered collection, a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

```java
VendingMachine vendingMachine = new VendingMachine() ;
…
List< Product > cookies = vendingMachine.getProductsForCategory( "Cookie" ) ;
```

You might want a sort-order field, just an integer number, as another member field on your `Product` class if the business (your client) wants to list certain products ahead of others. With such a field, the `getProductsForCategory` method could sort the products.

Next we need to present each category’s list of products to the user. So we need a user-interface.

Make another class to interact with the user via the console. The UI class knows about public interface of the vending machine object, but the vending machine does not know about the console nor the user. The vending machine only knows about the products it offers.

The UI object will access each category of products from the vending machine, getting a list. The UI object will loop through those objects to present a menu to user. Based on user's feedback, the UI object builds a collection of the products and quantities ordered by the user. You might write another class for this "shopping cart" or "order pad" of the user's choices, with a total price calculated.

In more realistic work, a vending machine would also need to manage its inventory. But I suppose that aspect is outside the scope of your schoolwork assignment.